# Stdout captured from pipe in Python is truncated

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I want to capture the ouput of `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` in Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 10.04.

```
from subprocess import Popen 
from subprocess import PIPE

p1 = Popen(["dpkg", "--list"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "linux-image"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
stdout = p2.communicate()[0]
```

The content of stdout is:

```
>>> print stdout
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.31-14.48   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.31 on x86
ii  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-22.36   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
ii  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-23.37   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
ii  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-24.43   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
ii  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-25.44   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
ii  linux-image-ge 2.6.32.25.27   Generic Linux kernel image
```

However, this is not the same as running `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` in a shell:

```
cschol@blabla:~$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-2.6.31-14-generic         2.6.31-14.48                                    Linux kernel image for version 2.6.31 on x86
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-22-generic         2.6.32-22.36                                    Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-23-generic         2.6.32-23.37                                    Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-24-generic         2.6.32-24.43                                    Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-25-generic         2.6.32-25.44                                    Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
ii  linux-image-generic                   2.6.32.25.27                                    Generic Linux kernel image
```

Looking at the first line, one can see that the output in Python is truncated:

```
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.31-14.48
```

instead of

```
rc  linux-image-2.6.31-14-generic         2.6.31-14.48
```

Why does it do that and is there a way to get exactly the same output in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["dpkg", "--list"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env={'LANG':'C'})
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "linux-image"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=p2.communicate()
print(out)
```

The `dpkg` command's output depends on the value of the LANG environment variable.
Setting `LANG=C` in `subprocess.Popen` will make `dpkg`'s output more like what you see from the terminal.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks! Is this something you just have to know or is it documented anywhere? `man dpkg' does not mention LANG at all.

Comment: @cschol: Unfortunately, I don't know of any documentation; I happened to learn about this issue here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=6943778#post6943778.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use grep !

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["dpkg", "--list"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env={'LANG':'C'})
out,err=p1.communicate()
for o in  out.split("\n"):
    if "linux-image" in o:
        print o
```